# Ignore all the folders that have sub folders in it using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a folder that consists of many folders, in that some have files only and other has subfolders and inside it, and that has some more files in it.
I want to write a shell script to ignore all the folder that has subfolder and anything included in it

example: this directory: /tmp/orders-temp has below files:

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  3 18:38 201201040230_abcd.1of3

> > it has comes zip and xml files

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  3 18:38 201201040230_abcd.2of3

> > it has comes zip and xml files

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  3 18:38 201201040230_abcd.3of3

> > it has comes zip and xml files

drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Dec  3 18:53 201201040230_abcd_90975

> > it has some sub directories

and we want only 201201040230_abcd_90975 to be ignored as it contains more sub-folders in it, i.e.:

cd 201201040230_abcd_90975

ls -rlt

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  3 18:42 201201040230_abcd-01

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  3 18:42 201201040230_abcd-02

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  3 18:42 201201040230_abcd-03

we need to ignore all of these this.

i.e. output should come to be:

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  3 18:38 201201040230_abcd.1of3

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  3 18:38 201201040230_abcd.2of3

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  3 18:38 201201040230_abcd.3of3

Also, we can get a different name next time for the folders so automation should be dynamic and nothing to be hard coded.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Print the structure of the data typing `find` without parameters.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you want to achieve. What do you mean with "ignore all the folder that has subfolder and anything included in it"? Do you want to do something with all other folders, i.e. those that neither contain subfolders nor files?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a directory tree:

```
/tmp
└── orders-temp
    ├── 201201040230_abcd.1of3
    │   ├── bar1.xml
    │   └── foo1.zip
    ├── 201201040230_abcd.2of3
    │   ├── bar2.xml
    │   └── foo2.zip
    ├── 201201040230_abcd.3of3
    │   ├── bar3.xml
    │   └── foo3.zip
    └── 201201040230_abcd_90975
        ├── 201201040230_abcd-01
        │   └── foo4.zip
        ├── 201201040230_abcd-02
        │   └── foo5.zip
        └── 201201040230_abcd-03
            └── foo6.zip
```

As you can see, the directory `201201040230_abcd_90975` contains subdirectories in it.
Then how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$1                  # assign to the target directory

while IFS= read -d "" dir; do
    if [[ -z $(find "$dir" -type d -mindepth 1) ]]; then
                        # if the directory has no subdirectories in it ...
        echo "$dir"     # or do something here
    fi
done < <(find "$dir" -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print0)
                        # find directories in "$dir" of level one depth
```

Result:

```
$ ./this_script /tmp/orders-temp/

/tmp/orders-temp/201201040230_abcd.1of3
/tmp/orders-temp/201201040230_abcd.2of3
/tmp/orders-temp/201201040230_abcd.3of3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tree ./work_dir                          
work_dir
├── 1.txt
├── 2.txt
├── 3.txt
└── next_folder
    ├── 1.txt
    ├── 2.txt
    └── 3.txt

1 directory, 6 files
```

**vim find_files.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

WORK_DIR=~/work_dir/

find $WORK_DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

save the file and:

```
chmod +x find_files.sh && ./find_files.sh

/home/user/work_dir/1.txt
/home/user/work_dir/3.txt
/home/user/work_dir/2.txt
```

***-maxdepth 2*** will find all files inside ***next_folder*** too.

If you want to eliminate the root directory, but print all other (nested ones):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

WORK_DIR=~/work_dir/
FOLDERS_TO_SEARCH=$(find $WORK_DIR -maxdepth 1 -type d)

count=0
for i in $FOLDERS_TO_SEARCH
do
        count=$(($count+1))
        if [[ $count -eq 1 ]];then
                echo "Skipping root directory: $i"
        else
                find $i -maxdepth 1 -type f
        fi
done
```

Comment: maxdepth 1 gives the folder which i don't want, i tried that and it does not seems to work in my case, i.e. it give
3.txt
└── next_folder
    ├── 1.txt
    ├── 2.txt
    └── 3.txt
which i don't want.

Output from the terminal: find . -maxdepth 1 -type d
.
./abcd_BB-Clien_hisense_P.2of3
./abcd_BB-Clien_hisense_P.1of3
./abcd_BB-Clien_hisense_P.3of3
./abcd_BB-Clien_hisense_P_90975

i only want:

./201201040230_BB-Clien_hisense_P.2of3
./201201040230_BB-Clien_hisense_P.1of3
./201201040230_BB-Clien_hisense_P.3of3

and this i folder i don't want : ./abcd_BB-Clien_hisense_P_90975

Comment: Added another example of how to eliminate root dir.